# C# Adding database information to a listbox

Tags: c#, database

I've been having a big problem with having information from a database (access) appearing in a listbox that I have created. I am naturally not using SQL to insert the information, and just want the table from access to fill the listbox automatically. I have established connection to the database as I have a login system currently working, I mainly get the error of cannot convert 'string' to 'int' currently. Any help is appreciated! Code is written below.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication7\WindowsFormsApplication7\NewOOP.mdb"))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * from Menu", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //if (Reader.HasRows)
            if (Reader.HasRows)

            {
                Reader.Read();
                listBox1.Text = Reader.GetString("Item");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On what line do you get the error? How does the Menu table looks?

Comment: `listBox1.Text = Reader.GetString("Item");` here `Item` is what actually ? string or int

Comment: Item is one of the rows from the database called Menu, and that is where i get the error. (in the "Item")         List<String> Item = new List<String>(); Is added before the code above.

Comment: Try using an integer number instead of `"Item"` in `GetString` method.

Comment: `public override string GetString(int i)`   Gets the value of the specified column as a string.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that great at C#, can you just give me a brief example of something like that please?

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try and come back to you in abit, thank you

Comment: Had a little bit of a fiddle and still having a problem, when I replaced the code you have given I get the error "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial” and "no suitable method found to override". I'm only guessing that I haven't defined something correctly since adding in the new code?